# Loader not resizing to child

Tags: qt, qml, loader

From the QML Loader documentation, I got "If an explicit size is not specified for the Loader, the Loader is automatically resized to the size of the loaded item once the component is loaded.", I have the following code:

```
Loader
{
    id: loaderRoot
    active: false
    sourceComponent: content
    property bool opened
    property var modal

    onLoaded:
    {
        loaderRoot.opened = Qt.binding(function() { return item.opened });
        loaderRoot.modal = Qt.binding(function() { return item.modal });
    }

    function open()
    {
        active = true;
        loaderRoot.item.open();
    }

    function close()
    {
        active = false;
        loaderRoot.item.close();
    }

    Component
    {
        id: content

        Popup
        {
            id: root
            implicitWidth: 751
            implicitHeight: layout.implicitHeight
        ...
```

But the width of the Loader is always 0.

Comment: There should be no problem with this. Out of curiosity, does it work better if you change the `Popup` to something more simple, like a `Rectangle`.

Answer (score 0):

Sizing of a `Popup` usually is based on its content. So instead of setting sizes for the popup, size the content. Simpel example with an `Rectangle` in the popup:

```
Loader
{
    id: loaderRoot
    active: true
    sourceComponent: content

    Component
    {
        id: content

        Popup
        {
            id: root
            visible: loaderRoot.active

            Rectangle {
                color: "gray"

                implicitWidth: 300
                implicitHeight: 200
            }

        }
    }
}
```

From the [QT Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls-popup.html#details):

> The implicitWidth and implicitHeight of a popup are typically based on
> the implicit sizes of the background and the content item plus any
> insets and paddings. These properties determine how large the popup
> will be when no explicit width or height is specified.

Comment: I did that, the example provided above is simplified to not make the code that I show unnecessarily complicated. This doesn't solve the problem of the loader not taking the size of the Popup though.